# Is it possible to use dynamic SQL or host variables in DB2 control center?

Tags: db2

I need to test some prepared statements that run slowly.

The control center uses JDBC.

In DB2 there's the `CREATE VARIABLE` statement. I guess it creates a variables on server, not a prepared statement parameter.

I need something like these:

```
select * from sysibm.sysdummy1 where 1=?;
SQL0313N  The number of host variables in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is not equal to the number of values required.

select * from sysibm.sysdummy1 where 1=:b1;
SQL0312N  The host variable "b1" is used in a dynamic SQL statement, a view definition, or a trigger definition.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a bash/batch script and execute it from db2clp

```
db2 connect to mydb
export b1=value
db2 "select * from sysibm.sysdummy1 where 1=$b1"
```

The script will replace the content of the variable.